# Setting mode bits during OS system calls

Tags: process, operating-system, job-scheduling

I wanted to know exactly whose responsibility is it to set the mode bits during system calls to the kernel.

Does the job scheduler manage these bits, or is the whole Process Status Word (PSW) a part of the Process Control Block?

Or is it the responsibility of the interrupt handler to do this? If so, how does the Interrupt Service routine (being a routine itself) get to perform such a privileged task and not any other user routine? What if some user process tries to address the PSW ?Is the behavior different for different Operating Systems?

Answer (score 1):

Alot of the protection mechanisms you ask about are architecture specific. I believe that the Process Status Word refers to an IBM architecture, but I am not certain. I don't know specifically how the Process Status Word is used in that architecture

I can, however, give you an example of how this is done in the case of x86. In x86, privileged instructions can only be executed on ring 0, which is what the interrupt handlers and other kernel code execute in.

The way the CPU knows whether code is in kernel space or user space is via protection bits set on that particular page in the virtual memory system. That means when a process is created, certain areas of memory are marked as being user code and other areas, where the kernel is mapped to, is marked as being kernel code, so the processor knows whether code being executed should have privileged access based on where it is in the virtual memory space. Since only the kernel can modify this space, user code is unable to execute privileged instructions.

The Process Control Block is not architecture specific, which means that it is entirely up to the operating system to determine how it is used to set up privileges and such. One thing is for certain, however, the CPU does not read the Process Control Block as it exists in the operating system. Some architectures, however, could have their own process control mechanism built in, but this is not strictly necessary. On x86, the Process Control Block would be used to know what sort of system calls the process can make, as well as virtual memory mappings which tell the CPU it's privilege level.

While different architectures have different mechanisms for protecting user code, they all share many common attributes in that when kernel code is executed via a system call, the system knows that only the code in that particular location can be privileged.